# How to make lockdown and unlock commands discord.py

Tags: discord.py

Im trying to make a lockdown and unlock command using discord.py rewrite. I have the code but it doesn't work at all. Can someone help me?

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_channels = True)
async def lockdown(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, send_messages=False)
    await ctx.send( ctx.channel.mention + " ***is now in lockdown.***")

@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
async def unlock(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, send_messages=True)
    await ctx.send(ctx.channel.mention + " ***has been unlocked.***")
```

Comment: It works for me fine

Comment: Please check if your bot has the permissions and Intents he needs.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue. The commands work on every other server except for the one I'm testing it on. It turns out that That server makes everyone admin as soon as they join.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, to enable the necessary bot permissions:

```
@client.command()
@has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
async def lockdown(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role,send_messages=False)
    await ctx.send( ctx.channel.mention + " ***is now in lockdown.***")

@client.command()
@has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
async def unlock(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, send_messages=True)
    await ctx.send(ctx.channel.mention + " ***has been unlocked.***")
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my unlock command hope it helps you

you have to use overwrites  [TextChannel.set_permissions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=text%20channel%20permission#discord.TextChannel.set_permissions)

```
@client.command()
async def unlock(ctx, role:Optional[Role], channel:Optional[TextChannel]):
    role = role or ctx.guild.default_role
    channel = channel or ctx.channel
    async with ctx.typing():
        if ctx.author.permissions_in(channel).manage_permissions:
            await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
            overwrite = channel.overwrites_for(role)
            overwrite.send_messages = True
            await channel.set_permissions(role, overwrite=overwrite)
            unlock_embed = discord.Embed(
            title= ("UNLOCKED"),
            description= (f"**{channel.mention}** HAS BEEN UNLOCKED FOR **{role}**"),
            colour=0x00FFF5,
            )        
            unlock_embed.set_footer(text=ctx.author.name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
            unlock_embed.set_author(name=client.user.name, icon_url=client.user.avatar_url)
            unlock_embed.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.guild.icon_url)    
            await ctx.channel.send(embed=unlock_embed, delete_after=10)
            print("unlock")
        else:
            error3_embed=discord.Embed(title="ERROR", description="YOU DONT HAVE PERMISSION", colour=0xff0000)
            error3_embed.set_thumbnail(url='https://images.emojiterra.com/google/android-11/512px/274c.png')
            error3_embed.set_footer(text=ctx.author.name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
            error3_embed.set_author(name=client.user.name, icon_url=client.user.avatar_url)
            await ctx.channel.send(embed=error3_embed, delete_after=10)
```

Comment: add some explanations